# How do I get a list of worker/process IDs inside a strongloop cluster?

Tags: node.js, strongloop

It looks like each process in a Strongloop cluster is considered a worker, and therefore if you use a tool like node-scheduler that schedules jobs and you have multiple workers, the job is executed multiple times.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
 // execute code
}
```

Since this doesn't seem to be possible, I wonder if there is a way to get a list of all worker or process IDs from inside the node app so that I can do this same sort of thing with one worker? This will need to be something dynamic, as `cluster.worker.id` does not appear to be a reliable way to do this since the worker IDs are unpredictable.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. "strongloop cluster" isn't a thing, its  a node cluster: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/cluster.html
2. No such API exists, and it wouldn't help you, you'd need to implement some kind of consensus algorithm to choose one of a (dynamic, workers can die and get replaced/restarted) set of workers as the "singleton"
3. Compose your system as microservices, if you need a singleton task runner, make it a service, and run it with a cluster size of 1.
4. This isn't really a cluster problem, its an inability to scale problem, isn't it? Cluster does internal scaling, you can limit to one for the scheduling service.... but when you will scale across multiple VMs (multiple Heroku dyno's, multiple docker containers, etc.) this will still fall apart... which will be the source of the timed node-schedule jobs?